# No definition of [libsensors4-dev] for OS [osx]

Tags: ros, rosdep, macbook, rosdep-install, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to install Ros Indigo on my macbook pro running OS X Yosemite. I'm following the instructions on the installation guide exactly, and everything runs smoothly until I have to run the following command:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

which fails with this error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
diagnostic_common_diagnostics: No definition of [libsensors4-dev] for OS [osx]
```

I couldn't find a solution for this problem in the troubleshooting section of the installation guide, or anywhere else online. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199874/no-definition-of-%5Blibsensors4-dev%5D-for-os-%5Bosx%5D/) by [ahmedallibhoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21191/ahmedallibhoy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is the result of the recent addition of the libsensors node to diagnostics: https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/pull/34

I've opened a ticket for this: https://github.com/ros/diagnostics/issues/36

As a workaround, you can remove the dependency on libsensors4-dev from the manifest in diagnostic_common_diagnostics and remove the build rules for the libsensors-monitor node from its CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-09**:
This should be fixed in the latest version of diagnostics, 1.8.7.